# Set global hotkey with Python 2.6

Tags: python, keyboard, wxpython, hotkeys, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanna setup a global hotkey in python 2.6 that listens to the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> on windows, please help me

Comment: This topic is also covered [here][1], however using Python 3.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615087/python-how-to-create-a-global-hotkey-on-windows-with-3-arguments/24654577#24654577

Comment: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.add_hotkey

Answer (score 9):

Tim Golden's [python/win32](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i.html) site is a useful resource for win32 related programming in python.  In particular, this example should help:

- [Catch system-wide hotkeys](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest [pyhk](http://www.schurpf.com/python/python-hotkey-module/). It allows for global wide hotkey registration in python and comes with examples and documentation. Pyhk builds on [pyhook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Hotkey registration is as simple as:

```
pyhk.addHotkey(SomeHotkey,SomeFunction)
```

Comment: Yes, windows only since it is based on pyhook.

Answer (score 3):

The [RegisterHotKey](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#RegisterHotKey) method of the `wx.Window` class is what you're looking for -- as the docs say,

> Registers a system wide hotkey. Every
>   time the user presses the hotkey
>   registered here, this window will
>   receive a hotkey event. It will
>   receive the event even if the
>   application is in the background and
>   does not have the input focus because
>   the user is working with some other
>   application. To bind an event handler
>   function to this hotkey use EVT_HOTKEY
>   with an id equal to hotkeyId. Returns
>   True if the hotkey was registered
>   successfully.

So, make an instance of `wx.Window, register the hotkey you want with this method, and possibly do a [PushEventHandler](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#PushEventHandler) if ypu'd rather handle the event(s) in a separate event handler rather than in the window itself (the latter being the default).

Is there anything else in this procedure that is not entirely clear to you...?  If so, please edit your question to add whatever further problems you may have!

Comment: Since RegisterHotKey accepts keys from win32con that solution will not work for him cause he needs VK_<letter> which is absent in win32con!

Answer (score 0):

If you want hotkeys in your wxPython program (which I assume you do because of the wxPython tag), then you should use a wx.AcceleratorTable.