# How to create a global hotkey on Windows with 3 arguments?

Tags: python, hotkeys, registerhotkey, global-hotkey

Just like Ctl, Alt + delete

I want to write a program, which uses global hotkeys with 3 or more arguments in python. The assigned function should only perform when I press all three keys on my keyboard. For example alt, windows and F3.

```
win32con.VK_F3, win32con.MOD_WIN, win32con.VK_F5
```

This is the current program I want to run, however its output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python32\Syntax\hot keys\hotkeys2.py", line 41, in <module>
   for id, (vk, modifiers) in HOTKEYS.items ():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The Program:

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import win32con

byref = ctypes.byref
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

HOTKEYS = {
  1 : (win32con.VK_F3, win32con.MOD_WIN, win32con.VK_F5),
  2 : (win32con.VK_F4, win32con.MOD_WIN),
  3 : (win32con.VK_F2, win32con.MOD_WIN)
    }

    def handle_win_f3 ():
  #os.startfile (os.environ['TEMP'])
  print ("Hello WOrld! F3")

def handle_win_f4 ():
  #user32.PostQuitMessage (0)
    print ("Hello WOrld! F4")

def handle_win_f1_escape ():
    print("exit")
    sys.exit()

HOTKEY_ACTIONS = {
  1 : handle_win_f3,
  2 : handle_win_f4,
  3 : handle_win_f1_escape
}

for id, (vk, modifiers) in HOTKEYS.items ():
  print ("Registering id", id, "for key", vk)
  if not user32.RegisterHotKey (None, id, modifiers, vk):
    print ("Unable to register id", id)

try:
  msg = wintypes.MSG ()
  while user32.GetMessageA (byref (msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
    if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
      action_to_take = HOTKEY_ACTIONS.get (msg.wParam)
      #print(" msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:")
      if action_to_take:
        action_to_take ()

    user32.TranslateMessage (byref (msg))
    user32.DispatchMessageA (byref (msg))

finally:
  for id in HOTKEYS.keys ():
    user32.UnregisterHotKey (None, id)
    print("user32.UnregisterHotKey (None, id)")
```

[Registering 3 hotkeys? Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168258/registering-3-hotkeys-possible)
Explains how one can use assign one key that needs to be pressed and then if two of which either needs to be pressed. However I won’t that the function only performs when all there are pressed simultaneously. I took

Comment: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, if you wanted alt, windows and F3, wouldn't you need to use `win32con.VK_F3, win32con.MOD_ALT, win32con.MOD_WIN` for the `HOTKEYS` entry?

However, it doesn't really make sense to say press <kbd>F3</kbd> with modifiers of the <kbd>Win</kbd> **and** <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

The error on the line:

```
for id, (vk, modifiers) in HOTKEYS.items ():
```

is because the value of each dictionary entry is a variable length `tuple`. Here's a way to handle that which also bitwise **OR** s all the modifier values together in preparation for passing them as a single argument to `RegisterHotKey()`.

```
from functools import reduce

for id, values in HOTKEYS.items ():
    vk, modifiers = values[0], reduce (lambda x, y: x | y, values[1:])
    print ("Registering id", id, "for key", vk)
    if not user32.RegisterHotKey (None, id, modifiers, vk):
        print ("Unable to register id", id)
```

It would have been easier to work on your problem if your code was indented properly and followed the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) recommendations. Please consider doing so in the future.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone interested in *details and a more elaborate example* regarding this topic, I recently wrote a short program demonstrating the hotkey functions provided by win32con. The program allows you to specify and test any hotkeys you want via command line:

> **Usage:** `python.exe hotkey.py MOD_ALT VK_UP` -> test hotkey ALT + Arrow UP

```
# Imports
import win32con
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes
import sys

#
# Functions
#
def dispatch_hotkey(msg):
    mod = msg.lParam & 0b1111111111111111
    key = msg.lParam >> 16
    bit = bin(msg.lParam)[2:]
    print("\n*** Received hotkey message (wParam: %d, lParam: %d)" % (msg.wParam, msg.lParam))
    print("lParam bitmap: %s" % bit)
    print("lParam low-word (modifier): %d, high-word (key): %d" % (mod, key))
    print("-> Hotkey %s with modifier %s detected\n" % (keys[key], mods[mod]))

#
# Main
#

# Build translation maps (virtual key codes / modifiers to string)
# Note: exec() is a hack and should not be used in real programs!!
print("\n*** Building translation maps")
mods = {}
keys = {}
for item in dir(win32con):
    if item.startswith("MOD_"):
        exec("mods[item] = win32con." + item)
        exec("mods[win32con." + item + "] = '" + item + "'")
    if item.startswith("VK_"):
        exec("keys[item] = win32con." + item)
        exec("keys[win32con." + item + "] = '" + item + "'")

# Process command line
print("\n*** Processing command line")

mod = "MOD_WIN"
key = "VK_ESCAPE"
for param in sys.argv:
    if param.startswith("MOD_"):
        if param in mods: mod = param
        else: print("\nInvalid modifier specified (%s). Using default.\n-> Use '--list-mods' for a list of valid modifiers." % param)
    if param.startswith("VK_"):
        if param in keys: key = param
        else: print("\nInvalid key specified (%s). Using default.\n-> Use '--list-keys' for a list of valid keys." % param)

if "--list-mods" in sys.argv:
    print("\nAvailable modifiers:")
    for item in dir(win32con):
        if item.startswith("MOD_"): sys.stdout.write(item + ", ")
    print("\b\b ")

if "--list-keys" in sys.argv:
    print("\nAvailable keys:")
    for item in dir(win32con):
        if item.startswith("VK_"): sys.stdout.write(item + ", ")
    print("\b\b ")

# Register hotkey
print("\n*** Registering global hotkey (modifier: %s, key: %s)" % (mod, key))
ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterHotKey(None, 1, mods[mod], keys[key])

# Wait for hotkey to be triggered
print("\n*** Waiting for hotkey message...")
try:
    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
        if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
            dispatch_hotkey(msg)
            break
        ctypes.windll.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
        ctypes.windll.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))

# Unregister hotkey
finally:
    ctypes.windll.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, 1)
```

**Please note that this program is intended for demonstration purposes only** as parts of the program (e.g. exec function) should not be used in production environments. Also note that with this approach, you won't be able to override built-in hotkeys like WIN + E etc., they will simply be ignored and still perform the built-in functions (e.g. opening Explorer).

**Another Way** (courtesy of @martineau)

Here's how to build the translation maps without using `exec()`:

```
print("\n*** Building translation maps")
mods = {}
keys = {}
for item, value in vars(win32con).items():
    if item.startswith("MOD_"):
        mods[item] = value
        mods[value] = item
    elif item.startswith("VK_"):
        keys[item] = value
        keys[value] = item
```

Comment: Suggest to make this an [Active State Python Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) and maybe post a link to it in a comment, rather than as a non-answer to a vaguely related question here on this website.