# Add global hotkey to toogle the display of GUI for PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a program with PyQt5. By default the GUI is hidden in system tray. I can right click the icon in the system try to open the GUI. I am wondering if I can set a global hotkey so I can toggle the main GUI shown and hidden. It will save me a few mouse click.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look here: [PyGlobalShortcut](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGlobalShortcut)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a global hotkey on Windows with 3 arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615087/how-to-create-a-global-hotkey-on-windows-with-3-arguments)