# Python - Listen for keybind in the background

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way I can listen for keybinds while a Python program is running in the background? For example, let's say my program is running and I am in a different window. I want to listen for a `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + F2` keypress, and then execute a function from that. Is that possible using Python? I am targetting Windows.

Comment: This is going to depend on which OS you are targeting.

Comment: It will also depend on the terminal you are using. Long story short it is more an environmental question than a Python one. So you have to describe exactly your environment (OS, version, terminal application)

Comment: It'll be Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615087/how-to-create-a-global-hotkey-on-windows-with-3-arguments/24654577#24654577