# How to execute code with keypress in python 2.7?

Tags: python, user-interface, keypress

does anyone know how i can execute code by key press in python 2.7? I'm thinking that maybe i should make an invisible window and on key-press it executes code which i can have under a function? does anyone know how i can achieve that?

I'm trying to make something that takes screenshots and i have this, but i want it to be under a key-press instead of every time you run the program.

```
import wx
import random
import getpass
from time import gmtime, strftime
Time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
User = getpass.getuser()
app= wx.App()
screen = wx.ScreenDC()
size = screen.GetSize()
bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
del mem  # Release bitmap
Time = Time.replace(':','-')
Name = Time + '.png'
Name = Name.replace(' ', '%20')
bmp.SaveFile(Name, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Is there anyway i can make this activate underkeypress?

Comment: For key availabe in all system you will have to register this key in system or read keys directly from system - and it depends on system

Comment: Look for some keylogger in Python - it knows how to grap pressed key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a minimized pygame window to get the key presses:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))

pygame.display.iconify()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
        #DO something if the player hits the UP arrow key
        print 'up!'
```

Comment: But what if minimized window loose focus ?

Comment: I can say only - this method doesn't work on Linux :/

Comment: :) everything depends on system :)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question I think, answer is here: [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

The idea is to use the os library to implement the getch() function you would use if you were writing in C.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Set global hotkey with Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337973/set-global-hotkey-with-python-2-6)

Probably you could use [pyHook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/) if you use Windows.

Or some method used in [pyKeylogger](https://github.com/amoffat/pykeylogger/blob/master/keylogger.py) if you use Linux.

Seems you use wxPython so see [RegisterHotKey in wxWindows](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#RegisterHotKey)